# Can a 5S LIPO battery be changed to a 3S and a 2S?

Tags: battery

Newbie to robotics here!

I bought a 5S LIPO but now realise that it is overkill. And these things are expensive!

So, given that (as far as I know) the pack is apparently made up of individual cells of 3.7 volts each, is there any way in which I could somehow (safely) separate out the cells to get a 3S and a 2S or even single 1S cells?

Comment: Obligatory  message about [safety concerns with Lithium Ion](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/safety_concerns_with_li_ion): puncturing the battery with something metal can cause venting of gasses and/or fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a Lipopack it looks basically like this:

[image]

There you can see the single cells with some cables attached to them.

If you want to open a lipo pack you have to cut the packaging with knife....
This is more or less everything you have to do. You will have 5cells which wired in series. just cut the cables to divide them in 3-2 and then you have to solder two cables.

There is one Thing you have to careful with: Try to not damage the cells with the knife, because lithium is an alkali metal and these metals react violently with the oxygen in the air. At the end the cell will ignite itself (it won't explode, don't worry) and the fumes may be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes theoretically you can split 5S lipo in indivisual cells as 5S represents it is pack of 5 cells connected in Series.(S in 5S denote connection in series). But practically you have to be extremely cautious while doing this as lipos are dangerous to handle and even more dangerous when you are splitting them apart.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said yes it is possible. I made it few times when i needed less height(stacked cells side-by-side), but **SAFELY** no. The only safely method would be to buy 2 or 3 s battery! You can damage your self.